# SRS light on and possible bad rear bearing Chevy Aveo

Tags: chevrolet, bearing, aveo

A couple of months ago the airbag light went on for no apparent reason. When I turn the ignition on, it goes off, and turns on again, without blinking, and with no errors (read with a cheap scanner). I have read in some forums and many people fix it by cleaning the yellow connectors under the seats. I did that, but the light is still on.
The car was due for revision, so I took it to the mechanic today and he told me that it could be because the belt retracts slowly and there could be a failure in the whole module, but I think it is because it is just dirty, and that has nothing to do with it.
Are there any more airbag connectors I can clean? What else could I look at? I still have to check the fuse.

The mechanic also told me that, on the way to the workshop, he noticed that the car sounded a lot, and that it could be a bad rear bearing. It's true that the car makes noise, the typical sound of driving on the road, and I thought it might be because it's a cheap car and has little insulation.
I was reading about bad bearings and one of the symptoms is that the car pulls to the side he told me the bearing was bad, and that does happen, I just innocently thought it would be because of bad steering wheel adjustment or something similar.

What do you think about it? Thank you in advance

Forgot the model: Chevrolet Aveo LS 2012ish, 1.2 manual

Comment: You cannot read SRS codes with a "cheap" scanner. It has to specifically be able to do SRS codes. Most which do SRS also do ABS as well. These are separate from OBDII codes.

Comment: Your mechanic should have a tool that can read srs codes. Also the seatbelt module can definitely cause the srs light to come on. The last time I had an srs light it was due to a bad seatbelt connector (buckle) and replacing it turned the light right off

Comment: The mechanic just called me. He asked me if I've ever made a short with the battery, because he gets that error in the srs computer with the fancy scanner, and he's going to look for a second hand one.

Comment: Before a bad bearing starts pulling a car one way or the other, which is a sign of being very late in the bearing's life, it starts making noises.  I'm guessing your mechanic noticed that while moving the car to check your SRS issue.

Comment: Okay okay. I am no mechanic but I know a little. I will jack the car and shake all wheels in all directions, and If I find some play and a bad noise spinning the wheel it will mean the bearing is bad right?